# Undefined method when trying to square each element in array

Tags: ruby, undefined, nomethoderror

I am trying to write a method called `square_digits` that squares every digit in a given number. I wrote:

```
def square_digits(num)
  number_array = num.to_s.split("")
  num_to_int = number_array.to_i
  num_squared = num_to_int.each{|n| n**2}
  return num_squared.join("")
end
```

When trying to run `square_digits(3212)`, which should return `9414`, I get the following error message:

```
`block in square_digits': undefined method `**' for "3":String (NoMethodError)
from `each'
from  `square_digits'
from  `
'
```

I'm not quite sure what I should do to fix it; any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm there are a few problems here:

With the input `123` it should error on:

```
num_to_int = number_array.to_i
```

With:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_i' for ["1","2","3"]:Array`

You want:

```
num_to_int = number_array.map(&:to_i)
```

Also

`num_squared = num_to_int.each{|n| n**2}`

doesn't return the results of `each` just the original array.

So with the first fix it will just return `"123"`

you want:

```
num_squared = num_to_int.map{|n| n**2}
```

So the final function looks like:

```
def square_digits(num)
  number_array = num.to_s.split("")
  num_to_int = number_array.map(&:to_i)
  num_squared = num_to_int.map{|n| n**2}
  return num_squared.join("")
end
```

Although i'm confused about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I was suppose to post the same code, but you bit me with 30sec ;) 1+

Comment: Dickie, consider yourself warned: I'll report you if you bite anyone else.

Comment: @CarySwoveland sorry warned? What for?

Comment: I was referring to a spelling mistake in  @Gagen's comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this ;)

```
def square_digits(num)
  num.to_s.split('').map { |n| n.to_i ** 2 }.join("")
end
```

**Or**

```
def square_digits(num)
  num.to_s.chars.map { |n| n.to_i ** 2 }.join("")
end
```